# What are these trees in the front of the picture?

Tags: identification, trees

Here are the trees I'm wondering about:

[image: picture of trees]

They are growing in Hong Kong. They have moderate length leaves pointing downwards, and are twice as tall as road signs.

They look like young palm trees, but I'm not certain of that.

What are they?

Comment: Looks like a palm tree. There are quite a number of palms http://www.trebrown.com/palms_arecaceae.php. Perhaps you can get a picture closer up showing it's fruits or flowers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are [*Phoenix roebelenii*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_roebelenii),  a [species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species) of [date palm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(palm)) [native](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_plant) to southeastern Asia. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_roebelenii):

> *Phoenix roebelenii*, is a popular [ornamental plant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornamental_plant) in gardens in tropical to warm temperate climate areas.
>
> *Phoenix roebelenii* is a small to medium sized, slow-growing slender [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree) growing to 2–3 metres (6.6–9.8 ft) tall. The [leaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf) are 60–120 cm (24–47 in) long, [pinnate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinnation), with around 100 leaflets arranged in a single plane (unlike the related [*P. loureiroi*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_loureiroi) where the leaflets are in two planes). Each leaflet is 15–25 cm (6–10 in)15-25 cm long and 1 cm broad, slightly drooping, and grey-green in colour with scurfy pubescence below.